# How to have two functions that call each other C++

Tags: c++, mutual-recursion

I have 2 functions like this that does obfuscation on if loop:

```
void funcA(string str)
{
    size_t f = str.find("if");
    if(f!=string::npos)
    {
        funcB(str);        //obfuscate if-loop
    }
}

void funcB(string str)
{
     //obfuscate if loop
     funcA(body_of_if_loop);     //to check if there is a nested if-loop
}
```

The problem with this would be that `funcA` would not be able to see `funcB` and vice versa if I put `funcB` before `funcA`.

Would appreciate any help or advice here.

Comment: Why does everybody call it an if loop? There's absolutely no looping involved.

Comment: @chris well, it replaces for-loop construct, does it not?

Answer (score 21, accepted):

What you want is [forward declaration](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Forward_declaration).  In your case:

```
void funcB(string str);

void funcA(string str)
{
    size_t f = str.find("if");
    if(f!=string::npos)
    {
        funcB(str);        //obfuscate if-loop
    }
}

void funcB(string str)
{
     //obfuscate if loop
     funcA(body_of_if_loop);     //to check if there is a nested if-loop
}
```

Answer (score 12):

A [forward declaration](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Forward_declaration) would work:

```
void funcB(string str); 

void funcA(string str)
{
    size_t f = str.find("if");
    if(f!=string::npos)
    {
        funcB(str);        //obfuscate if-loop
    }
}

void funcB(string str)
{
     //obfuscate if loop
     funcA(body_of_if_loop);     //to check if there is a nested if-loop
}
```